# How do we know the kernel API change in what kernel version?

Tags: linux-kernel

for example: In the commit dc42cf74d98a39af30ecaf78e7fad7e265ae528f, I see the VFL_TYPE_VIDEO was removed, but I don't know what kernel version was introduce this?

Comment: API should be stable, but for such case: either googling (so you get possibly a rationale) or `git blame` on the line and you see when the line was changed (and so introduced). AFAIK there is no documentation on introducing new features (just a list of obsolete features which may be removed in future, without timeline)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45120/given-a-git-commit-hash-how-to-find-out-which-kernel-release-contains-it